# How to add jar in Eclipse to update the version ?

Tags: android, eclipse

I made my app for Android 4.3 and I'm almost done with that but now I want to upgrade it for **Android 4.4**.

Will it work by adding `android.jar` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to perform it.

1. Download latest version of android i.e **Andriod 4.4 (API 19)** using **Android SDK manager**.
2. Right Click your Project -> Properties -> Android -> Select desired API level
3. Update your Android Manifest file with min, max and target SDK support

You can not change `android.jar` file directly. You need to perform **step 2** to do so.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not work ... you need to update the SDK with Android SDK manager first. Then update the Eclipse ADT plugin and then go to your Android project, set the Android project build path to 19 and change the targetSDK to 19 as well in the Manifest.

The android.jar JAR file does not contain the Android framework code, but only stubs for the type signatures, methods, types, etc. The android.jar JAR file is only used for the Java compiler before deployment on an Android device. It is not bundled with your application. Once your application is deployed on the device / emulator, it will use the android.jar JAR file on the Android device. Calling methods from the android.jar JAR file throw a new RuntimeException("Stub!").